# I'd like to know how to sort this list I have by date modified

Tags: c++, qt

I am coding in qt 5.5 and I have a QDir to get all of my files from a single folder, and I am wondering how I can sort these files by date modified. I need to order them and them rename them 1, 2, 3, ...... until the end. I have that working, but I just need to find a way how to sort by date. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//MainWindow.h:
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFileDialog>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_toolButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


//MainWindow.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

QString path;
QStringList before;
QString suffix;
QDir folder;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_toolButton_clicked()
{
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    ui->listWidget_2->clear();
    path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"), "/home", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    ui->lineEdit->setText(path);
    folder.setPath(path);
    before = folder.entryList(QDir::Files);
    ui->listWidget->addItems(before);

    QString temp = before.at(0);
    QStringList pieces = temp.split(".");
    suffix = pieces.value(pieces.length() - 1);

    int amount = folder.count();
    QStringList after;

    for (int x = 0; x < amount;)
    {
        x++;
        after << QString::number(x) + "." + suffix;
    }

    ui->listWidget_2->addItems(after);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < before.count(); x++)
    {
        int i = x;
        folder.rename(before.at(x), QString::number(i++) + "." + suffix);
    }
}


//Main.cpp:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `folder.entryList(QDir::Files, QDir::Time)`

Comment: @igor-tandetnik This worked, but can you use more than 2 QDir sorts?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What more do you want to sort?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik like, reversed time ordered files. I'd need QDir::Files, QDir::Time, QDir::Reversed, but I can only use two in context.

Comment: `folder.entryList(QDir::Files, QDir::Time | QDir::Reversed)`.